# Append a objeto a otro objecto?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

estoy tratando de hacer un tipo de append adentro de un objeto, pero no estaria sabiendo que metodo utilizar para lograrlo. Por lo que busque, recomiendan utilizar un array, pero sinceramente no me siento cxomo utilizando ese metodo. (Cuando utilizo db no me refiero a ninguna base de datos, es solamente un objeto JS)

```
var db = {
    users: {
        user1: {
            name: 'user-1',
            email: 'user-1@gmail.com'
        },
        user2: {
            name: 'user-2',
            email: 'user-2@gmail.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Estaria intentando que con una linea de codigo llegase al codigo mostrado abajo.

```
var db = {
    users: {
        user1: {
            name: 'user-1',
            email: 'user-1@gmail.com'
        },
        user2: {
            name: 'user-2',
            email: 'user-2@gmail.com'
        },
        user3: {
            name: 'user-3',
            email: 'user-3@gmail.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan facil como crear una nueva propiedad que sea tu nuevo objeto:

```js
var db = {
    users: {
        user1: {
            name: 'user-1',
            email: 'user-1@gmail.com'
        },
        user2: {
            name: 'user-2',
            email: 'user-2@gmail.com'
        }
    }
};

db.users.userNuevo = {
            name: 'user-2',
            email: 'user-2@gmail.com'
}

console.log(db);
```

Comment: Perfecto, justo esto buscaba! gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Que te parece esto:

```js
var db = {
    users: {
        user1: {
            name: 'user-1',
            email: 'user-1@gmail.com'
        },
        user2: {
            name: 'user-2',
            email: 'user-2@gmail.com'
        }
    }
}

var newUser = {
    name: 'user-3',
    email: 'user-3@gmail.com'
}

db.users.user3 = newUser;
console.log(db);
```